# How do I create an external transformer class when using the ElementApi plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-elementapi

I've been trying to clean up my `elementapi.php` file, and one very important step in making it more DRY is to have reusable transformer classes.

But I cannot seem to get it to work, the following gives me a blank page.

So far in my `elementapi.php` file I have the following.

```
'api/articles' => function() {
// I have also tried to place this line at the very top of the file.            
require_once craft()->path->getConfigPath().'transformers/EntryInfoTransformer.php';

            'criteria' => [
                'section' => 'blog',
                'order' => 'postDate desc',
            ],

            'elementsPerPage' => 5,
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'transformer' => new EntryInfoTransformer(),
        },
```

and my EntryInfoTransformer.php file has

```
<?php

require craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'elementapi/vendor/autoload.php';

use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
class EntryInfoTransformer extends TransformerAbstract{
    public function transform(EntryModel $entry) {
        return [
            'id' => $entry->id,
        ]
    },
}
```

I don't get any errors, nothing in either the php or craft logs, just a blank while page. This has been tested on php 5.5 & 5.6. Site runs normally otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a whitescreen because you've got some PHP syntax errors in both files. Craft isn't reporting them because those config files get loaded before Craft has had a chance to bootstrap.  The underlying errors should be recorded in your web server's error logs depending on your default server configuration.

Try these:

**elementapi.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

require_once craft()->path->getConfigPath().'transformers/EntryInfoTransformer.php';

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/articles' => function() {
            return [
                'criteria'        => [
                    'section' => 'blog',
                    'order'   => 'postDate desc',
                ],
                'elementsPerPage' => 5,
                'elementType'     => 'Entry',
                'transformer'     => new EntryInfoTransformer(),
            ];
        },
    ]
];
```

**EntryInfoTransformer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

require craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'elementapi/vendor/autoload.php';

use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class EntryInfoTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(EntryModel $entry){
        return [
            'id' => $entry->id,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried both files, nothing else but the code above in my files, and it still returns a blank page. I've checked the system level log files and they output issues for me, but not of the kind that I want and the last one to be logged was 2 days ago. https://www.dropbox.com/s/c958xysma589x5q/Screenshot%202015-10-09%2021.24.17.png?dl=0

Comment: Updated. The transformer class needs to be in the Craft namespace.